# Azure website redirect one https URL to another https URL same domain

Tags: azure, redirect, https, azure-web-app-service

I have a website that is an Azure App Services.

The URL is https://www.triviaweb.net/. I own the domain triviaweb.net (registrar is GoDaddy).

I would like https://triviaweb.net/ (no www) to be automatically redirected to https://www.triviaweb.net/ because I don’t want to get another certificate to make https happen.

Is this possible to set this up in Azure or my registrar GoDaddy?

Answer (score -1):

You can set HTTPS Only setting to 'On' under 'Custom domain' in the portal which would redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: The questions is not http to https redirect. It's https to https redirect for the same domain.